# How to show a chef-client configuration?

Tags: chef-infra

The command **chef-client --help** does show all chef-client options. But it does not seem to show any attribute that lists what is the current chef-client configuration ?

Is there a config file that is contains the defined configuration. For instance, I am interested in checking what is the chef-server URL of a specific chef-client ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a config file where you can find details like - log level , log location , chef server url etc

In Linux this file is located under `/etc/chef/client.rb`